# Point-Biserial Correlation (r) for non homogeneous independent samples

Tags: correlation, t-test, independence

I am performing an independent t-test, in which the independent variable is the "group" which has two values A and B representing an approach the participants used, and the dependent variable is a metric for accuracy "Recall" which has numeric values ranging from 0 to 100.  Total number of participants is 18 (9 in each group) randomly assigned to the groups.

What is the formula I should use to use in calculating the effect size in terms of the Point-Biserial Correlation (r), knowing that the two independent variables are non homogeneous according to Levene's test?

Comment: What variable(s) are ordinal - DV or IV? You say `two independent variables` what do you mean? "Independent T-test" is done with one grouping independent variable with 2 groups.

Comment: Hello ttnphns, the IV is the "group" which has two values A and B representing an approach they used, the DV is metric for accuracy "Recall" which has numeric values ranging from 0 to 100.

Comment: How can you possibly calculate a correlation coefficient on *independent* data? Correlation measures are for pairs/dependent groups.

Answer (score 2):

You realise that the point-biserial is numerically equivalent to the Pearson, right? You can look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) or use an [online calculator](http://vassarstats.net/pbcorr.html).

It sounds odd to me to be calculating a correlation between different people in the two groups. Correlation always works on paired observations. Do you not just want an effect size using something like [Cohen's d](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_d)?

Comment: Hello stan, I have already calculated Cohen's d, but another part of the study was about the "precision" variable which was not normal and I had to use the Mann-Whitney test and I had to report effect size as r=z/sqrt(n).

So, I thought I should have similar types of effect size reported for both recall and precision.